# What does a recruiter ( or the interviewer ) look for in a resume of a mid level software engineer?

Tags: interviewing, resume, hiring-process, job-change, work-experience

I have been working as a software engineer for the past 2 years since graduating from college. Recently, I have been contacted by a recruiter for a new position which I am interested in. He asked for my resume but I am not sure what people expect in a mid level software engineer's resume. I have my skills, professional experience listed but I don't know what else should I add. Can someone shed some light on this? Another thing that I was thinking about is how much information I can mention in the experience section as I don't want to give too much information about the things that my current company is working on.

Comment: Add what you would in any other resume: Your skills, experience and qualifications, and how they pertain to the role you are applying for :)

Comment: I dunno about the 'on-hold'. I mean, I get it, but I think a good resume is actually quite objective.

Answer (score 6):

The absolute most important thing that the recruiter is looking for in your resume is this:

- do your skills and abilities solve the problem that the company looking for a candidate has

Every section, word, phrase should be geared toward the end of explaining to the recruiter and hiring manager why you would be able to fill the position effectively.

- Do you have experience in any of the skills that the position will use?
- If not, how do the skills you do have apply to the role?
- Do you have relevant education?
- What have you accomplished in your current role that shows them you'll accomplish great things in the new role?
- Do you code or learn on your own time? (e.g. you like the field)

And so on.

In a nutshell, that's what recruiters are looking for when trying to fill any position: can you do the job effectively.

As far as being a mid-level engineer, the title isn't as important as what you know and what you've done. A lot of the time titles like junior, intermediate and senior only specify a political situation in a company (e.g. this guy has only worked here for four months, let's call him junior and pay him a junior wage).

So your approach as someone with more experience isn't fundamentally different than the approach of someone with less experience than you, you just happen to have more experience to back up your credibility. Whatever the job is that you're applying for, prove that you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

What people look for in a resume changes with the wind, the position of the moon and from person to person. There's no particular formula for what to add and what not to have. You could have all the right stuff on there but if it looks bad or is otherwise presented poorly, then it's not going to help. One person can tell you it looks good while the next person may not like it. Take resume critique with a grain of salt.

At this level of your career, you should be highlighting your experience. Have you stepped up to higher-level projects? Have you knocked saud projects out of the park, per se? Have that stand out in your resume.